# Borderlands 3 crashing startup July 2020 update

Tags: technical-issues, borderlands-3

I've been getting this the past few times I started Borderlands 3. It shows the logo screens, it says "Optimizing Shaders" then this appears and it closes. I've tried restarting my computer (this time it wouldn't restart even when I left it on overnight. I had to hold the power button). Admittedly I'm running a very old rig from 2013 so that may be part of it.

Samsung Series 7 Gamer; Windows 10 64-bit Home; 24GB DDR3 RAM; System Model: 700G7C; BIOS: P02ABA.041.130320.DK; Processor: Intel Core i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.4GHz; DirectX Version: 12; Graphics Card: AMD Radeon HD 7870M, AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6825), Internal DAC(400MHz), VRAM: 2026 MB, DirectDraw Acceleration, Direct3D Acceleration, AGP Texture Acceleration.
[image: Error Screen Readout Borderlands 3]

Comment: Try to [clear shaders cache](https://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/t/borderlands-3-crashing-for-anyone-else/4384461) or [use DX11](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2020/03/20/borderlands-3-optimising-shaders-takes-forever-steam-fix/).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error when my power cut out during the shaders being updated.  My error included the message:

> Lowlevelfatalerror line 242

I found a [solution by Dirges on the Gearbox Forums](https://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/t/ue4-low-level-fatal-error-crash-on-launch/4543288/12). The cause of this crash is a bad or corrupt .ini file that Borderlands 3 can't process. To fix it, try this:

- Find where your Borderlands 3 config exists. Mine was at `<username>\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 3\Saved\Config`
- Delete (or rename) the folder `WindowsNoEditor` which contains a bunch of `.ini` files. This will force Borderlands 3 to rebuild the `.ini` files.
- It appears that the most common reason for these kinds of errors is bad DX11/12 support. You can try to inspect or edit the `GameUserSettings.ini` file to update the `PreferredGraphicsAPI` to DX11 or DX12 as your graphics card supports.

Comment: DX12 was the issue for me, thanks :)